# Can we use schedulers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, javascript-framework

I want to use schedulers in JavaScript.My requirement is like I have to call an url for every 10 seconds, so that the page to update with the newly loaded data.Is JavaScript support these type of requirements or else is there any way to get my requirement.

Thanks

Comment: simple answer yes.using setInterval or setTimeOut,you must have searched before posting a question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am an Ruby back-end developer so I don't have much knowledge about JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need  `setInterval()`

```
setInterval(function() {
  //do something for every 10 sec.
}, 1000);
```

Example :http://jsfiddle.net/5BAkx/

Comment: Actually it was in the question.

Comment: @Rajiv007 I added the comment there :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  setInterval(function(){ /*call url */ }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like below:

```
setInterval(function() {
   // do the ajax job;
}, 10000);
```

Comment: is setInterval Jquery function, or it can be used in pure Js too?

Comment: @JoeHalfFace It's just pure js.

Answer (score 0):

you can open URL inside `<iframe>` tag and use following meta tag to refresh your page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
```

Place above meta tag between `<head></head>` tags. "300" is the number of seconds.